# How to turn the arrow(image) so that it does not turn CalloutView

Tags: swift, mapkit, mkannotationview, mkpointannotation, calloutview

I need to turn the arrow on the map (customAnnotationView) so that the calloutView does not rotate (Example 1).

When I rotate only the image:
The arrows are not set in the center and of different sizes (Example 2).

Example 1
[image]

Example 2
[image]

```
Example 1
annotationView?.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat((-180.0 * .pi / 180) - -customPointAnnotation.ang))

Example 2
annotationView?.image = UIImage(named: customPointAnnotation.pinCustomImageName)?.rotate(radians: CGFloat((90.0 * .pi / 180) - -customPointAnnotation.ang))
```

Comment: You are not rotating image you are rotating annotation ... so rotate image and then assign it to annotation.

Comment: example 2, I rotate the image like that. When I create a subview, they are duplicated after redrawing, as well as the result, as in  example 2

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will Solve your problem

```
 let pinImage = UIImage(named: "customPointAnnotation.pinCustomImageName")
        let size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50) // size of your choice
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
        pinImage!.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))
        let resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        let rotatedImage =  . resizedImage rotate(radians: CGFloat((90.0 * .pi / 180) - -customPointAnnotation.ang)) //if still not set do check by changing image or by slightly changing redians angle values.
        annotationView?.image = rotatedImage
```

Comment: I use your code, it deviates the arrow to the side from the center, as in example 2
.

Comment: slightly change the angle CGFloat((85.0 * .pi / 180).

Comment: Or your Arrow image needs to some updations, i am glade it resolved the size issue :) .

Comment: CGFloat((85.0 * .pi / 180). – CGFloat ((85.0 * .pi / 180). - so arrows pointing down. the image is even to me, I don’t think that it is a problem

Comment: Okay got the point do not use this method in viewFor annotation all the time because viewFor annotation reuses old annotation and changes its angle according to old annotation angle.

Comment: Check an answer over here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33163155/custom-annotation-image-rotates-only-at-the-beginning-of-the-program-swift-ios

Comment: Another good answer is 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30964002/swift-mkannotationview-rotate

Comment: i get this error - "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" when I redraw annotations

Comment: I can’t turn the arrows correctly. Your method puts them not evenly and spoils the quality of some shooters. If you turn exactly the annotation, then the arrows become smooth and "reuse" does not worsen their display, why?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39508296/how-to-rotate-custom-userlocationannotationview-image-using-mapkit-in-swift  check method 3 over here.